# ajax code stops running when I pass a string from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

php

```
$sortBy = array('upload_date','wall_views','wall_downloads');
        $sort = 'upload_date';
        if(isset($_GET['sort']) && in_array($_GET['sort'], $sortBy)){
            $sort = $_GET['sort'];
        }
```

ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var per_page = <?php echo $per_page;?>;     //$per_page = 3
    var last_page = <?php echo $last_page;?>;   //$last_page = 4
    var sort = <?php echo $sort;?>;             //$sort = upload_date
    $(function(){
        $('.more').live('click', function(){
            var page = $(this).attr('id'); //get the last id

            $.ajax({
                type:   'GET',
                url:    'pagination.php',
                data:   {page: page, per_page: per_page, last_page: last_page, sort: sort},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#itemContainer').append(data);
                }
            }); //ajax code end
        }); //live end
    });     //function end - when DOM is ready.
</script>
```

the problem occurs when I try to pass a string (`upload_date`) variable to ajax, I'm not sure if I'm passing the string correctly, this code works fine if only integers/digits are passed into the code. What I'm I doing improperly here? please help.

Comment: I suggest putting quotes around the string like this: `var sort = '<?php echo $sort;?>';`

Comment: was able to fix it as well! I did something like `var sort = <?php echo "'" . $sort . "'";?>;` haha! thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add quotes around string variables. otherwise your generated javascript will look like variable names rather than string literals.

Like so:

```
var sort = "<?php echo $sort;?>"; //$sort = upload_date
```